# Why is it not allowed to define vectors of variables in a scoping construct?

Tags: scoping, assignment

The following command assigns 1 to `a`, 2 to `b` and 3 to `c`:

```
{a,b,c} = Range[3]; {a,b,c}
(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

But inside `Block`, `Module` or `With` it doesn't work, because "only assignments to symbols are allowed"

```
Block[{{a,b,c} = Range[3]}, {a,b,c}]
Block::lvset: "Local variable specification {{a,b,c}=Range[3]} contains {a,b,c}=Range[3], which is an assignment to {a,b,c}; only assignments to symbols are allowed."
```

Since:

> Those scoping constructs take symbols as elements of the first argument, optionally setting them to values. Whether that could be extended to nested lists is an open question I guess, but the fact is the language does not support that at this time. –  Daniel Lichtblau

Is there any reason the syntax cannot be extended to this form?
What's the difference between evaluating the same command inside and outside the scoping construct?

Comment: Those scoping constructs take symbols as elements of the first argument, optionally setting them to values. Whether that could be extended to nested lists is an open question I guess, but the fact is the language does not support that at this time.

Comment: The first argument of `Block` (and also `Module`, `With`) is a declaration list. Assignments in declaration list are subject to a different semantics than assignments in the body of the scoping construct. Massive assignments of the type you described are simply not allowed in scoping constructs, syntactically. A link to [related discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373526/error-generating-localized-variables-as-constants/).

Comment: You can always do `Block[{a,b,c},{a,b,c} = Range[3]]`